# How to fix this spreadsheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some albums data with some value for each date. If I don't find a value for a particular date then it should return the previous date value if that is also not available need to pull the last updated value.

```
=if(sumifs('POs iTunes'!$D:$D,'POs iTunes'!$C:$C,concatenate("*",B$8,"*"),'POs iTunes'!$E:$E,text($A11,"dd/mm/yy"))=0,iferror({INDEX(B12:B,MATCH(true,B12:B>0,0))},0))
```

I used above formula if the new dump added to the existing data it is returning false values.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vKvvTj6r1xIrQbINPiWjobircET2CyMOacqSLzNhs8A/edit#gid=452699219).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What problem are you having _in particular_? I am not sure it is entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Halfer, I need the count for each album for particular day, if that particular day doesnt value then the previous day value to be returned.